# CanCan gem Inner Workings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cancan

I'm trying to learn gems\ruby better and decided to look at CanCan gem. 
I looked at the code a lot and there are some things I don't understand -

1)How is the code made available to my controllers\models? I realize that when you install the gem it requires all of cancan's files , but wouldn't my controllers need to actually inherit from Ability module to get the "can?" method for example ?

2)CanCan wants you to define an 'ability' class , together with a 'current_user' in your controller . But who is instantiating this ability class?

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability
 def initialize(user)
```

I couldn't find any Ability.new or new Ability or such , and couldn't understand how the gem is using my current_user method to pass it to the constructor.